# i want this java script to show the answer below the button not on the button , please have a look

Tags: javascript, dom

so basically this code make the text go on the button but i want it to show below the button so every time i click the button the text would update as the following: https://jsfiddle.net/santon/mc15vy4f/ <----- example

```
  var myBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");

 var clickTracker = {
      count:0,
    getMessage: function() {
    var message;

    switch(this.count) {
        case 1: message = "You pushed the button"; break;
        case 2: message = "You pushed the button (again)."; break;
        case 3: //fall Through
        case 4: //fall Through
        case 5: //fall Through
            message = "You pushed the button "+ this.count + " times."; break;
        default: message = "Stop pushing the button"    
    }
    return message;
   }
};


 function processClick() {
    clickTracker.count++;
       this.innerHTML = clickTracker.getMessage();
 }

 myBtn.addEventListener("click", processClick);
```

Comment: Then do that. Currently you are assigning the text to the button. What is your issue with using a different element instead? We can't really reach you if we don't know what your issue is.

Comment: im not quite sure how to do that

Comment: You must have thought about *something*. Did you make yourself familiar with the DOM API at all? The simplest solution would probably be to add a new element with some ID after the button and to `document.getElementByID('someID')` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`this.innerHTML = clickTracker.getMessage();`

you are telling the button to change it's inner HTML.
If you want the text/html to appear after the button you can do the following:

```
 var myBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");
var textContainer;

 var clickTracker = {
      count:0,
    getMessage: function() {
    var message;

    switch(this.count) {
        case 1: message = "You pushed the button"; break;
        case 2: message = "You pushed the button (again)."; break;
        case 3: //fall Through
        case 4: //fall Through
        case 5: //fall Through
            message = "You pushed the button "+ this.count + " times."; break;
        default: message = "Stop pushing the button"    
    }
    return message;
   }
};


 function processClick() {
    clickTracker.count++;
       var text = clickTracker.getMessage();
       if(!textContainer){ //checking if container is not yet set
           textContainer = document.createElement("div"); //creating the element
           this.parentElement.appendChild(textContainer);//appending to parent of button
       }
       textContainer.textContent = text;
 }

 myBtn.addEventListener("click", processClick);
```

Comment: it doesnt work for some reason , could u maybe post on this link and try running it https://jsfiddle.net/santon/mc15vy4f/

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this:

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<p id="stat"></p>
```

JS code like this :

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myButton");

var clickTracker = {
    count:0,
    getMessage: function() {
        var message;

        switch(this.count) {
            case 1: message = "You pushed the button"; break;
            case 2: message = "You pushed the button (again)."; break;
            case 3: //fall Through
            case 4: //fall Through
            case 5: //fall Through
                message = "You pushed the button "+ this.count + " times."; break;
            default: message = "Stop pushing the button"    
        }
        return message;
    }
};


function processClick() {
    clickTracker.count++;
    document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = clickTracker.getMessage();
}

myBtn.addEventListener("click", processClick);
```